# "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" error when creating html table from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a html table out of a JSON for a message board website I am trying to make. I have a JSON called "msgs" for messages which contains dictionaries for the username, message and date. I am trying to extract each element to add to the table, but I am getting an error.

I originally had all the rows being appended to the table individually, but I created a variable "table" to which I add all the elements and append everything at the end.

```
msgs=[{username:"John"
       message:"I am John"
       date: "2019-09-05 18:02:53.000000"}
      {username:"Mary"
       message:"I am Mary"
       date:"2019-09-06 18:02:53.000000"}
]

function buildTable(msgs){
        let table = ""
        table += '<table style="width:100%" border="1">';
        for (var i = 0; 1 < msgs.length; i++){
            let username = msgs[i]["username"];
            let message = msgs[i]["message"];
            let date = msgs[i]["date"];
            table += '<tr>';

            table += '<td>' + username + '</td>';
            table += '<td align="left">'+ message + '</td>';
            table += '<td align="right">' + date + '</td>';

            table += '</tr>';
        }
        table +='</table>';
        $("#messagecontainer").append(table);
```

Take line 5 for example.

```
  msgs[i][username] 
= msgs[0][username]
= "John"
```

It should be John, but I receive an error that says:

"Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

I tried logging msgs[i][username] to the console, and it printed "John" correctly. However, it just doesn't work when I try to add it to the table.

Comment: Replace 1 < msgs.length to i < msgs.length

Comment: `msgs` is not valid JS. Missing a lot of commas: https://jsfiddle.net/39Lm067g/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that your for loop has `1 (number one) < msgs.length` and not `i (variable i) < msgs.length`? Thus, the condition is always true and the loop runs out

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your loop is going in infinite mode. Inside for loop you are checking `1 < msgs.length` and this condition will be always true. Since you have only two objects in your msgs array that why in the third iteration it is throwing

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined